# How Iterate nested for loop on table rows using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, ngfor, formarray

I wan't to itereate for loop for displaying resonce data into table rows. and I want that data values in array format. Please tell how I can get this. below is the my code.

**HTML file**

```
<div class="row">
        <form *ngIf="!isError" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="SubmitForm()">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 userRows" formArrayName="criteria">
          <div *ngFor="let quantity of getCriteria().controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-4"><label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{mylabels.criteria}}
                    </label></th>
                  <th class="col-4"><label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{mylabels.rating}}
                    </label></th>
                  <th class="col-4"><label for="colFormLabel"
                      class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{mylabels.feedbackcomment}}</label></th>
                </tr>
                </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                <tr *ngFor="let feedbacksList of substring">
                  <td class="col-4">
                    <!-- <p class="innerproddesc" [innerHtml]="feedbacksList"></p> -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-90" formControlName="criteriaText"
                      value="{{substring}}">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select class="col-4" formControlName="rating" class="rating" (change)="selectedRating($event)">
                      <option [value]="rating" *ngFor="let rating of rating">
                        {{rating}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-4"><input type="text" class="form-control w-90" formControlName="feedbackcomment">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-end">
            <button [routerLink]="['/user-list']" type="button"
              class="btn btn-gray btn-sm mr-4">{{mylabels.cancel}}</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
           &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid"
              class="btn btn-blue btn-sm  ">{{mylabels.save}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
```

**TS File**

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({

criteria: this.fb.array([]),
skill: '',
typeofinterview: '',
videoquality: '', overallrating: '',
 });

       ngOnInit(): void {

this.getCriteria().push(this.newCriteria());
 }

  get f() { return this.userForm.controls; }

   getCriteria(): FormArray {
    return this.userForm.get('criteria') as FormArray;

       }

      newCriteria(): FormGroup {
       return this.fb.group({
       criteriaText: '',
       rating: '',
       feedbackcomment: '',
       domainknowledge: ''

       });

       }
        getAllFeed() {
       this.apiService.httpGetCall('GetAllFeed').subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.feedList = res.feed;
        this.feedbList.forEach((feedres: any) => {
        this.feedCriteria = feedres.criteria;
        this.substring = this.feedCriteria.split('~');
        console.log("substring", this.substring);

        //output
            //             substring 
           // (3) ['New Feedback with CU1', 'New Feedback with CU2', 'New Feedback with CU3']
           // 0: "New Feedback with CU1"
          // 1: "New Feedback with CU2"
          // 2: "New Feedback with CU3"
         // length: 3

        })


      },
      (error: any) => {
         this.showLoader = false;
         this.isError = true;
         this.errorData = {
             reason: error.message,
         };
         }
         );
         }
         SubmitForm() {
          const urlarr: any = [];
              this.userForm.value.criteria.forEach((i: any) => {
              urlarr.push({
                criteriaText: i.criteriaText,
                 rating: i.rating,
                 feedbackcomment: i.feedbackcomment,
                 domainknowledge: i.domainknowledge,
                 });
                 });
                const savedata = {
              criteria: urlarr,
                 };

                console.log('savedata :', savedata);
                   }

                     }
```

I'm entring 3 values there for 3 rows as per response. Below is the screenshot for that
[[enter image description here][1]][1]

After clicking on Save button

I want output as follows

```
  criteria: Array(3)
0: {criteriaText: 'New Feedback with CU1', rating: '5', feedbackcomment:'feed 1' }
1: {criteriaText: 'New Feedback with CU2', rating: '6', feedbackcomment:'feed 2'}
3:{criteriaText: 'New Feedback with CU3', rating: '7', feedbackcomment:'feed 3'}
```

**But I'm getting only third row value there as like below:**

```
criteria: Array(1)
 0: {criteriaText: '', rating: '7', feedbackcomment: 'feed 3'}
 length: 1
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Please let me know how I can get my expected output. Please refer my screenshots for UI and output which I am getting

Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqEKB.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNFKV.png

Comment: Do you want to make a for loop to create as many rows as you want in the table, right?

Comment: I not sure why you get 3rows within only single call of method  `newCriteria()`

Comment: @AhmedSHA256 yes, I want to create many rows and want access values of that rows

Comment: @paranaaan I just decalred formcontrols in that method

Comment: Can try to add this line for 3 times `this.getCriteria().push(this.newCriteria());`, do the result change?

Comment: @paranaaan no we can't do that. If we added that 3 rimes then on UI same row will be added for 3 times. So, what we can do on UI for displaying single row

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
<tr>
 <td>{{mylabels.criteria}}</td>
 <td>{{mylabels.rating}}</td>
 <td>{{mylabels.feedbackComment}}</td>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
 <td>{{items[item ]?.id}}</td>
 <td>{{items[item ]?.name}}</td>
 <td>{{items[item ]?.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

Format and adapt this code as you need. Also, try to improve your question, Give your code a better formatting.

Comment: in my ts file code is well formatted but while adding here some gaps mismatches that's why it's not looking in better formatting. And what you suggest above that is not working in expected manner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. I am created FormGroup's inside FormArray. And that one working fine.